# about clang++ requirements for C++11

Tags: c++11, g++, clang

I would like to build some code in new C++11. Our machine allows only g++4.4.7 that is old for that. We have available also clang++ 3.4 that as far as I understood supports the new features.

While I am doing first tests with clang++ it looks like it does requires c++ header files from g++. Having available version g++4.4 this will prevent my code to use the new C++11.

Is it really so? Is there a way where I can use clang++3.4 to build C++11 code without having latest versions of g++ ?

Comment: Have a look at http://libcxx.llvm.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try libc++, on linux should work just fine
http://libcxx.llvm.org/